# Is static casting a good design in my situation?

Tags: c++, oop, casting, game-engine

I use game state manager (intro, main menu, gameplay etc) from [here](http://gamedevgeek.com/tutorials/managing-game-states-in-c/). However there is one problem. A very minimalistic example:

```
class cApp //manages the states and gives them access to window
{
public:
cApp (RenderWindow & ref) : window(ref) {}
void changeState(cState *);     //these function realy doesn't matter
void update();
void draw();

RenderWindow & window; //the same as in the article, this class not only manages state but gives them access to window etc

private:
std::vector <cState *> states;
}
```

The state:

```
class cState
{
public:
cState(cApp * ptr) : app(ptr) {}
virtual void update() = 0;
virtual void draw() = 0;
protected:
cApp * app;
}
```

So far everything is good. The problem is this is the part of basic framework. So the cApp is only very basic and gives access only to window. However there may be the case where the user wants to use networking in his game. Network engine isn't a part of single state so it must be at the more global (that means, cApp) level.

So the user does:

```
class cNetworkedApp : public cApp
{
public:
cNetworkedApp(RenderWindow & ref1, NetworkEngine & ref2)
: networking(ref2), cApp(ref1)
NetworkEngine & networking; //initialized in cNetworkedApp constructor
}

class CharacterCreationState : public cState
{
 CharacterCreationState(cApp * ptr) : cState(ptr) {}
 //implement pure virtual functions
 void draw()
 {}
 void update()
  {
      //THE PROBLEM
      //the state needs to access the network engine so casting is required
      cNetworkedApp * ptr = static_cast<cNetworkedApp*>(app))
      ptr->networking.sendSomething();
  }
}
```

The only obvious solution is to include everything what may be possible in cApp, however as I said this is a framework. Of course some engines like physics engine or sound engine are things which you put into a state so that's not problem, but things like networking system must be the one object available for all states. And not every app uses it.

Do I need to redesign this code or is it okay?

Comment: `dynamic_cast` won't even work since the classes aren't polymorphic.

Comment: Take the time to write correct code in the question. As it stands the definition of the base would not compile. While small mistakes can be *fixed* while reading, in this particular case, it is unclear whether any of the member functions in the base type are/should be virtual

Comment: I changed the code. Now it's good. ( i think )

Comment: @user1873947: No, it isn't.

Comment: @David Rodríguez what's wrog then? Despite the fact it's pseudocode.

Comment: From my previous comment: *it is unclear whether any of the member functions in the base type are/should be virtual*. I still see no `virtual` keyword. In the case of `cState` you can only but assume that they are since the `= 0` won't compile otherwise, but it is unclear in the case of `cApp`. Remember that it is **you** the one having a problem that needs solving, not **us**. Your part of the deal is helping us understand the problem, our part of the deal is trying to help you come to a solution. I personally won't spend time trying to second-guess your intent.

Comment: @David Rodríguez everything is crystal clear now in the code. The cApp class has NO virtual functions.

Comment: @user1873947: Then refer to Luchian's comment above

Comment: @David Rodríguez the question is about static_cast.

Comment: Well the code was wrong at the beggining but now everything is good in the code. Now it's not pseudocode but fully working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `cApp` may keep with it a named list of a polymorphic type `Engine`, ie `map<string,Engine*>`, then, your user may ask the `cApp` if it has a given engine.

`NetworkEngine` would be a subclass of the pure abstract `Engine`.

### Update

When dealing with a pointer that I you are sure that it is of the given specialized type, you should use `static_cast`, when you wanna query if the pointer can be casted to a type you should use `dynamic_cast`.

I, myself, have a safer approach for the first case, I use an assertion to guarantee that the type can be casted and use the `static_cast` in normal code:

```
Engine* fetchedEngine = cApp.fetch("network");
assert( dynamic_cast<NetworkEngine*>(fetchedEngine) != NULL );
NetworkEngine* network = static_cast<NetWorkEngine*>(fetchedEngine);
```

Only a object of type `NetworkEngine` should be putted on the "network" name, but maybe someone mistakenly put something else, the `assert` will make us safer without needing to worry about the overhead.

Comment: interesting approach. You are right, decoupling state manager from engine is a great solution here. I will wait and see if someone has other interesting solution.

Comment: and with this method I should prefer dynamic_cast or static_cast?

Comment: @user1873947 Editted my answer, take a look

Comment: @user1873947 Note that to dynamic_cast work, you will need a vtable. Just create a virtual destructor and you are done.